# Sorting elements in the same class by their branch and ancestors

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've got the following html (all the elements name*, name**, and name*** are unknown):

```
    <div class="one">nameA</a>
    <div class="two">nameAA</a>
        <a class="three">nameAAA</a>
        <a class="three">nameAAB</a>
        </div>
    <div class="two">nameAB</a>
        <a class="three">nameABA</a>
        <a class="three">nameABB</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="one">nameB</a>
    <div class="two">nameBA</a>
        <a class="three">nameBAA</a>
        <a class="three">nameBAB</a>
        </div>
    <div class="two">nameBB</a>
        <a class="three">nameBBA</a>
        <a class="three">nameBBB</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and trying to make this dictionary:

names=
    {nameA:[nameAAA, nameAAB, nameABA, nameABB],
     nameB:[nameBAA, nameBAB, nameBBA, nameBBB]}

I'm using beautifulSoup select function but cannot link between the names in "three" descendant class it returns with the names of their ancestor in class "one".
Actually the result in my code is:
wordOnesText = [nameA, nameB]
wordThreesText = [nameAAA, nameAAB, nameABA, nameABB, nameBAA, nameBAB, nameBBA, nameBBB]

```
res = requests.get('address')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html.parser')
wordOnes = soup.select('.one')
wordThrees = soup.select('.three') or soup.select('.one > .two > .three')
```

Could you help me to link these two list in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
itemdict={}
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
for item in soup.select('.one'):
    itemlist = []
    name=item.contents[0].strip()
    for child in item.select('.three'):
        itemlist.append(child.text)
    itemdict[name]=itemlist

print(itemdict)
```

This should print.

```
{'nameA': ['nameAAA', 'nameAAB', 'nameABA', 'nameABB'], 'nameB': ['nameBAA', 'nameBAB', 'nameBBA', 'nameBBB']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this script. It utilizes `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) to group elements to key, values:

```
data = '''<a class="one">nameA</a>
    <a class="two">nameAA</a>
        <a class="three">nameAAA</a>
        <a class="three">nameAAB</a>
    <a class="two">nameAB</a>
        <a class="three">nameABA</a>
        <a class="three">nameABB</a>
<a class="one">nameB</a>
    <a class="two">nameBA</a>
        <a class="three">nameBAA</a>
        <a class="three">nameBAB</a>
    <a class="two">nameBB</a>
        <a class="three">nameBBA</a>
        <a class="three">nameBBB</a>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

def get_key_values(soup):
    current_key = None
    for v, g in groupby(soup.select('.one, .three'), lambda k: 'one' in k['class']):
        if v is True:
            current_key = next(g).text
        else:
            yield current_key, [i.text for i in g]

out = dict(get_key_values(soup))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'nameA': ['nameAAA', 'nameAAB', 'nameABA', 'nameABB'],
 'nameB': ['nameBAA', 'nameBAB', 'nameBBA', 'nameBBB']}
```

Comment: @Mohammadreza you need to import `pprint` module: `from pprint import pprint`